# Software requirements analysis or requirements engineering?

Tags: terminology, requirements

I've been looking around for some articles regarding to requirements analysis, but I'm a bit confused with the term, because based on Wikipedia [requirements analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis) is a stage of [requirements engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_engineering).

But once you search more, many of the websites use them interchangeably as in they mean the same, can you please help me clarify this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Requirements engineering is a term that includes all activities related to requirements - elicitation, analysis, documentation and specification, validation, and management. It might also involve some levels of modeling, ranging from the creation of use case models to more detailed collaboration with system architects and designers.

Requirements analysis is one aspect of requirements engineering that involves reviewing the requirements to ensure that all requirements are useful to building the product. For each requirement, the person or people performing the analysis will ensure they have the [characteristics of a good requirement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirement#Characteristics_of_good_requirements). Some source also consider early prototypes to be part of requirements analysis, since it helps to further understand and clarify requirements given by stakeholders or identify problems with the requirements.

To think of requirements engineering as a staged activity, however, it probably not a good idea. The various activities are ongoing throughout a requirements definition phase of the project. With some regards, requirements engineering also happens throughout the entire project. It just becomes useful to give names to activities to make it easier to discuss with others.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially speaking, Requirements Analysis is a subset of Requirements Engineering. Very often you come across a client or a scenario where the requirements are not clear or pre-determined and this is where you have to engineer (determine, analyse and design) the requirements and show them to the client to validate (according to their budget).

In order to conduct Requirements Engineering, it is almost essential to know UML and other modeling tools that assist in comprehending, understanding and designing the system.

Answer (score 0):

Requirements engineering sounds like a more formal process with a number of stages.

Requirements analysis, to me is the specific task of getting/figuring out requirements.

As such, I wouldn't consider them interchangeable.